# ConfigurationErrorsException using WCF serviceModel for Addin VS2008

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, wcf, add-in, configuration-files

I have a DLL (library project in vs2008), that calls to external web service. Project has a Service reference to external webservice

I have Unit test, and app.config (with servicemodel configuration) in unit test project, and all is right.

Now, I use Addin VS 2008, and has'nt configuration file like Windows Forms or Asp.net.
the addin is a dll and it has config file.

If I use WCF  (using my project DLL), the config system.servicemodel not found

I have seen this: 
http://vassiltonev.blogspot.com/2009/03/loading-custom-config-file-instead-of.html

but Adding a custom wcf behavior extension causes a `ConfigurationErrorsException`

> The type 'Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples.CustomTextMessageEncodingElement, CalidadCodigo.Integracion.CustomTextEncoder' registered for extension 'customTextMessageEncoding' could not be loaded. (E:\TFS\pro\AddIn\bin\Debug\MyAddIn.dll.config line 123

I test with Assembly QualifiedName in my extensions WCF but wrong.

any more suggestions or any sample code ?

my config

```
<extensions>
  <bindingElementExtensions>
    <add name="customTextMessageEncoding"
         type="Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples.CustomTextMessageEncodingElement,CalidadCodigo.Integracion.CustomTextEncoder, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
  </bindingElementExtensions>

</extensions>
```

The code

```
    internal static WebServicePortTypeClient CrearClienteWCF()
            {
                try
                {
                    return new WebServicePortTypeClient();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                    //TODO: not found serviceModel config

 var addInConfig = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);


                var endpointAddress = addInConfig.AppSettings.Settings[EasyVistaSvcEndPointAddress].Value;
                var endpoint = new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress(endpointAddress);

                return new WebServicePortTypeClient(EndPointConfigurationName, endpoint);

                // The type 'Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples.CustomTextMessageEncodingElement, CalidadCodigo.Integracion.CustomTextEncoder' registered for extension 'customTextMessageEncoding' could not be loaded. (E:\TFS\pro\AddIn\bin\Debug\MyAddIn.dll.config line 123)


                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK its not possible to use the ConfigurationManager in a DLL. I ran in the same issue while I wrote a Plugin for VS2010.

My Solution was to load the settings from a file an create the endpoint and endpointadress by myself in the code like this:

```
Uri myUri = loadUriFromFile();

var endpoint = new EndpointAddress(myUri); 

NetTcpBinding binding = GetNewTcpBindingFromFile(); 

return new WebServicePortTypeClient(binding, endpoint);
```

Comment: HOw can I create CustomBinding and extensions programatically ??

Comment: you can look at the xml code the visual studio generates in the app.config for the wcf service. That the serialized object it easy to see what property you have to fill.